# mouseover show div

Tags: javascript, html, show, onmouseover

I haven't been able to find the answer to this anywhere.

How do you make a hidden div appear when mousing over where it would have been?
Please do not tell me how to make a link, I know how to make a link ;)

I have tried:
a.) onmouseover set visibility to visible and onmouseout set visibility to hidden
this works in 0 browsers

b.) setting borders to 0px and background transparent and innerhtml to "" onmouseout and reverting onmouseover
this works in chrome

c.) This was the most popular answer on the internet, which i knew wouldn't work, but I tried anyway: make a container div set to visible and then do visibility visible and visibility hidden for the inner div

d.) Setting opacity to 1/100 and 0
works in chrome

e.) last resort: i tried making a transparent gif and having it display onmouseout
this also failed

I haven't tried jquery's .hover but I have read that it may not work correctly.

I have no other ideas. Will somebody help, please?

Comment: What's wrong with the opacity method?

Comment: works fine in chrome and webkit and i presume firefox, but it doesn't work in IE, of course!

Comment: But all you need is to set the filter to `alpha(opacity=XX)` to get IE6-8 support, as well.

Comment: i did, maybe i'm missing something here,

Comment: document.getElementById('ELE_' + id).style.opacity = 0;
document.getElementById('ELE_' + id).style.filter = "alpha(opacity=0)";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it right you want div element to show if you are over it and hide when the mouse is not over. If that's it you can do it only with html and css:

```
<head>
<style>
        #outerDiv{width:100px;height:100px;background-color:blue;}
        #innerDiv{width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red;display:none;}
        #outerDiv:hover #innerDiv {display:block;}
    </style>
</head>
<html>
    <div id="outerDiv">
        <div id="innerDiv">some text</div>
    </div>
</html>
```

The outer div is always visible and when it's hovered the inner one is shown.

Comment: how will outerdiv show up if its content is empty? It will not be visible.

Comment: The outer div has fixed dimensions - so it is visible. Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/wVpBu/

Comment: i think display:none got it to work, because it is working in jsfiddle for me in IE, thanks a lot Draganov!

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is going to help you: http://jsfiddle.net/eb4x9/
The mouseover event won't trigger when the div is hidden so you can detect it's position and size.
Here is the source:

**HTML**

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#foo {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    visibility: hidden;    
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).mousemove(function (event) {
    var div = $('#foo'), 
        divLeft = div.offset().left, 
        divTop = div.offset().top, 
        divWidth = div.width(), 
        divHeight = div.height();
    if ((event.pageX >= divLeft && event.pageX <= divLeft + divWidth) &&
        (event.pageY >= divTop && event.pageY <= divTop + divHeight)) {
        div.css('visibility', 'visible');
    } else {
        div.css('visibility', 'hidden');        
    }
});
$(document).mouseleave(function (event) {
    var div = $('#foo');
    div.css('visibility', 'hidden');        
});
```

Best regards!

Comment: yea i figured it might end up looking like this, but i was hoping for a simpler way, considering the div is circular. I would have to generate an array of points with an elliptical function, but oh well it's close enough! thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the display attribute of the div to 'block' along with the visibility attribute to 'visible' in your onmouseover event.

Set the display to 'none' and visibility to 'hidden' to hide.

Of course the trouble will be firing the mouse over on a hidden div.

This works in every browser I have ever used it in.

Comment: exactly. once it is hidden, I am stumped on what to do.

Comment: @Ryan gotcha, The trick will be to pick a div or object that will already be displayed --presumably, you have something displaying where the other one ought to be displayed--, then use the onmouseover event on that to set the attributes I mentioned.

Comment: @Ryan you could add an empty div with some height and width. onmouseover of this div set display of your original div to 'block'

Comment: @rahool, an empty div would still not display since the container is only as large as its contents. You could have a transparent image though.

Comment: @Jonathan, if the empty div have some height and width it should show. Please see the answer that i have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, having two divs one empty and other with your content and toggling between them on mouseover

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
function toggle() {
    var your_div = document.getElementById("your_div");
    var empty_div = document.getElementById("empty_div");

    if(your_div.style.display == "block") {
            your_div.style.display = "none";
            empty_div.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
            your_div.style.display = "block";
            empty_div.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

<style>
   #empty_div{width:100px; height:100px;}
   #your_div{width:100px; height:100px; border: 1px solid #000fff;}
</style>
</head> 

<body>
   <div id="your_div" onmouseover="toggle()">xyz</div>
   <div id="empty_div" onmouseover="toggle()"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there's an interesting thought. Not exactly what I had in mind, but it's definitely a cool approach.